# Edit data in MySQL Database with no Primary Key

Tags: mysql, webmin

I am using Webmin on an Idaq hosting package to manage my MySQL database. I have imported the database from a previous host and now find that I cannot alter any data that is in a particular table because of an error "Data in this table cannot be edited because it has no primary key."

In a php script I can alter data but really need to alter it from the control panel.

When I try and create a primary key field I get the following error "Failed to save field : SQL alter table `userbase` add `referenceNumber` smallint not null auto_increment failed : Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key"

I am well aware that any table should contain a primary key and this is my mistake , but can anyone offer some help please ?

Comment: Could you show us table's definition (CREATE TABLE...)?

Comment: Did my answer fix your problem?

Comment: Sorry for the late response , But it worked a treat Pez, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you aren't setting it as a key at the same time so it fails the `and it must be defined as a key` part, put key on the end.

Use

```
ALTER TABLE tableName ADD autoIncrementColumn MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT KEY
```

---

Extra Info from Johan in comments

> @Mick, To add to PEZ's answer, if you do not provide a primary key,
>   MySQL adds a hidden primary integer autoincrement key. In order to
>   override the hidden key, the alter table statement must specify the
>   addition of a new field and the assignment of the new PK in the same
>   line, otherwise the hidden PK will block the alteration.

Comment: @Mick, To add to PEZ's answer, if you do not provide a primary key, MySQL adds a hidden primary integer autoincrement key. In order to override the hidden key, the `alter table` statement must specify the addition of a new field and the assignment of the new PK in the same line, otherwise the hidden PK will block the alteration.

Comment: Thanks for the extra detail Johan, I didn't realise this!